# Reading in a .txt into ArrayList from another class

Tags: java, javafx

Reading in `instructions.txt` from `instructions.java` from a comma(,) delimited method for `InstructionsController` so that I may present it into a `TextArea` on `Instructions.xml`.

Having trouble figuring out once I've read in the file, how to pass over the `ArrayList` to another class to successfully use that data.

Using `about` in `handle` as a test button in the `InstructionsController` class.

Instructions.java

```
public class Instructions {

    private String[] identifier;

    private ArrayList<String> listName;
    private ArrayList<String> listDesc;

    public void dataLoader() {

        String fileName = "instructions.txt";
        Scanner scan;

        /*
         * Shows working path System.out.println(newFile(".").getAbsoluteFile());
         */

        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            // Iteration rather than iterable
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                int i = 0;
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                identifier = line.split(">");

                if(identifier[i].equals("TITLE")) {
                    listName.add(identifier[i+1]);
                } else if (identifier[i].equals("DESC")) {
                    listDesc.add(identifier[i+1]);
                } else if (identifier[i].equals("END")) {
                     i++;
                }
            }
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
            System.err.println("Failed to open instructions");
            System.exit(1);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getListName() {
        return listName;
    }

    public void setListName(ArrayList<String> listName) {
        this.listName = listName;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getListDesc() {
        return listDesc;
    }

    public void setListDesc(ArrayList<String> listDesc) {
        this.listDesc = listDesc;
    }
}
```

InstructionsController.java

```
public class InstructionsController implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>, Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button about, constants, professionPerks, teamCilantro, mainMenu, exit;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane background;

    @FXML
    private TextArea text;

    Main main = new Main();

    private List<String> name;
    private List<String> desc;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Instructions instructions = new Instructions();
        name = instructions.getListName();
        desc = instructions.getListDesc();
    }

    @FXML
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Button selected = (Button) event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) selected.getScene().getWindow();

        if (selected == about)

        if(selected == mainMenu) 
            main.switchScene("fxml/Title.fxml", stage);

        if(selected == exit) 
            stage.close();
    }
}
```

*sample text*
file input: instructions.txt

> TITLE> Profession Perks:
>
> DESC> Investor: Starts with $150 bonus "Starting Cash" for a total of $650 "Starting Cash".
>   Farmer: Starts with 250 "Pounds of Food" and has a perk to consume food for the party at a 75% rate compared to normal.
>   Handyman: Significantly less likelyhood of "Wagon" breaking down.
>
> END>

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to create an instance of the first class in the second class file. Or you can attempt to set your 'get' methods to static. Take a look at this previous SO answer.

> You need to create an instance of Class A and then access the values from Class B, for example:

```
public class ClassA {
  private int someInt;

  public ClassA() {
    someInt = 5;
  }

  public int getSomeInt() {
    return someInt;
  }
}

public class ClassB {
  public void someMethod() {
    ClassA instanceOfClassA = new ClassA();

    int someIntFromClassA = instanceOfClassA.getSomeInt();  //This is now 5;

    // Rest of your code here
  }
}
```

> Alternatively you can create it as a static method in `ClassA` and then call it in `ClassB` by using `ClassA.getSomeInt();`

[Passing an array from class A to class B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738017/passing-an-array-from-class-a-to-class-b)